# Okta SAML SLO response status is 'RequestDenied'

Tags: node.js, saml, saml-2.0, okta, onelogin

Integrating Okta SAML Single logout(SLO) into ServiceProvider. I am trying to make SLO request in two ways.
1. HTTP Redirect binding 2. HTTP POST binding. I configured SLO in okta dashboard.
Here is my HTTP Redirect binding Request:

```
function create_logout_request(issuer, name_id, session_index, destination) {
    var id, xml;
    id = '_' + crypto.randomBytes(21).toString('hex');
    xml = xmlbuilder.create({
        'samlp:LogoutRequest': {
            '@xmlns:samlp': 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol',
            '@xmlns': 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion',
            '@ID': id,
            '@Version': '2.0',
            '@IssueInstant': (new Date()).toISOString(),
            '@Destination': destination,
            'Issuer': issuer,
            'NameID': {
                '@Format': 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameidformat:emailAddress', // attributes start with @
                '#text': name_id // text node
            },
            'samlp:SessionIndex': session_index
        }
    }).end();

    return {
        id: id,
        xml: xml
    };
}
let xmlReqObj = create_logout_request(options.entity_id, options.name_id, options.session_index, idp_options.sso_logout_url);
let newXmlReq = xmlReqObj.xml.replace('<?xml version="1.0"?>', "");
let appendXmlVersion = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + newXmlReq;
let input = new Buffer(appendXmlVersion);
let compressed = zlib.deflateSync(input);
var samlEncodeReq = compressed.toString('base64')
let queryStr = "SAMLRequest=" + encodeURIComponent(samlEncodeReq) + "&SigAlg=" + encodeURIComponent("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/          xmldsig#rsa-sha256") + "&RelayState=" + encodeURIComponent(options.relay_state);
let sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
sign.update(queryStr);
let signature = sign.sign(sp_options.private_key, 'base64');
let logout_url = idp_options.sso_logout_url + "?" + queryStr + "&Signature=" + encodeURIComponent(signature);
res.redirect(logout_url);
```

Here is my HTTP POST binding Request:

```
var html = [
    '<!DOCTYPE html>',
    '<html>',
    '<head>',
    '<meta charset="utf-8">',
    '<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">',
    '</head>',
    '<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">',
    '<noscript>',
    '<p><strong>Note:</strong> Since your browser does not support JavaScript, you must press the button below once to proceed.</p>',
    '</noscript>',
    '<form method="post" id="myForm" action="https://lantronix-sharath.okta.com/app/lantronixorg730497_testsaml_1/exk5zzbhqflRfc0uM355/slo/saml">',
    '<input type="hidden" name="SAMLRequest" value="' + samlEncodeReq + '" />',
    '<input type="hidden" name="RelayState" value="' + options.relay_state + '" />',
    '<input type="submit" value="Submit" />',
    '</form>',
    '<script> function submitForm(){ document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); } submitForm(); </script>', 
    '</body>',
    '</html>'
    ].join('\r\n');

res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.send(html);
res.render(html);
```

I got SAML Response as below

```
<saml2p:Status xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:RequestDenied"/></saml2p:Status>
```

I tried with two types of SAML Logout Request xml forms. They are as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_d72db96681b9f6649ae862b21f5e175e74ed7aae19" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2018-08-03T07:14:02.548Z" Destination="https://lantronix-sharath.okta.com/app/lantronixorg730497_testsaml_1/exk5zzbhqflRfc0uM355/slo/saml"><Issuer>https://192.168.50.68:3000</Issuer><NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameidformat:emailAddress">csharath@lantronix.com</NameID><samlp:SessionIndex>_72507c647a10dd290a14b2991c2e88f5817b6ad332</samlp:SessionIndex></samlp:LogoutRequest>

<?xml version="1.0"?><samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_c942f734072c29dbc745e9ce764d7777b456908442" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2018-08-03T00:53:36.607Z" Destination="https://lantronix-sharath.okta.com/app/lantronixorg730497_testsaml_1/exk5zzbhqflRfc0uM355/slo/saml"><Issuer>https://192.168.1.2:3000</Issuer><NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:emailAddress">csharath@lantronix.com</NameID><samlp:SessionIndex>_4865368d3755a7c3a032134867bd769e1953d74790</samlp:SessionIndex></samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

Please help me out what is the SAML Logout request format?

Answer (score 0):

You need a client-side SAML stack e.g. [I need a SAML stack — now!](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

This then talks to a SAML identity provider.

Which IDP are you planning to use?

Once you have it all configured, the stack will handle all the messages (SP Initiated) or if your IDP supports it, you can start from the IDP (IDP Initiated).

**Update**

The best way to do this is to hook up both applications to the IDP. Then authenticate to the first app. When you go to the second app, the IDP will use SSO and the second app. will get a SAML token without the user having to authenticate again.

Comment: I am using SAML stack as OneLogin and Okta. Here the question is  domain1.com acts as ServiceProvider and it receives the SAML response from SAML stack(IDP). Then I want to send SAML response and ServiceProvider generated token to the domain2.com. But How to do that? If I do redirect from domain1.com to domain2.com I can able to send data in as a query parameters. But I am expecting another approach to do it.    Here domain2.com is an HTML hosted dumb server it doesn't handle REST calls from domain1.com. Can we able to send data from domain1.com to domain2.com by redirecting with POST method?

Comment: Are you trying to send that SAML token the app. received in domain 1 to another app, in domain2?